# Combine two rows into one in R

Tags: r

I encounter another challenge about combine two row into one based on identifier col.

My dataset looks like this:

```
var<-c("round","round","round","hhid","hhid","chid","chid","sex")
dfile<-c("df1","df2","df3","df1","df2","df1","df2","df1")
uniquevar<-c("df1::round","df2::round","df3::round", "df1::hhid","df2::hhid","df1::chid","df2::chid","df1::sex")
flag<-c("dup","dup","dup","dup","dup","dup","dup","NA")
df<-data.frame(var, dfile,flag)
```

I am trying to do

1. find the obs which is marked as "dup"
2. If it is marked as "dup", combine two/three/or multiple rows into one with format:
   df1::var  | df2::var  |df3::var

So, the ideal outcome would look like this

```
var      dfile.                    uniquevar                               flag
round    df1 |df2 |df3             df1::round | df2::round |df3::round      dup
hhid     df1 |df2                  df1::hhid | df2::hhid                    dup
chid     df1 |df2                  df1::chid | df2::chid                    dup
sex      df1                                                                NA
```

So far I can only do that manually in excel, that is really time-consuming. I appreciate if I could be told how to achieve that in R, which would be much faster considering the dataset contains over 600,000 obs...

Thanks a lot~~!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `paste` cells together after using `group_by(var)`. Use `sep = "::"` to specify the separator between different columns, and `collapse = " | "` for the separator representing rows. You can do this inside `summarize` from the `dplyr` package.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(var) %>%
  summarize(uniquevar = ifelse(all(flag == "dup"),
                               paste(dfile, var, sep = "::", collapse = " | "),
                               ""),
            dfile = paste(dfile, collapse = " | "),
            dup = flag[1]) %>%
  select(var, dfile, uniquevar, dup)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>  var   dfile           uniquevar                              dup  
#>   <chr> <chr>           <chr>                                  <chr>
#> 1 chid  df1 | df2       "df1::chid | df2::chid"                dup  
#> 2 hhid  df1 | df2       "df1::hhid | df2::hhid"                dup  
#> 3 round df1 | df2 | df3 "df1::round | df2::round | df3::round" dup  
#> 4 sex   df1             ""                                     NA
```